# Replace unicode strings

Tags: autohotkey

I have this code:

```
replace :=  {x:"y",≤:"\leq",≥:"\geq",∫:"\int",∑:"\sum"}


For what, with in replace
  f2::StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %what%, %with%, All
```

And it works to replace x to y. But I actually want to use this to replace a whole bunch of unicode math symbols to latex. This stringreplace function doesn't seem to work with unicode, any ideas how I could get what I want ? Is this the right place to ask this ?

Comment: It is indeed a character coding issue. I can't even get these char's represented in SciTE4, but as soon as I replace them with "normal" char's (¥ ß ñ ÿ) it works like a charm.

Comment: Did the answer help you to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I create this script in good old Microsoft Notepad (on Windows 7) and save it as Replace.ahk in the format `Unicode`, it runs like a charm!

```
ClipBoard= x123y123≤123≥123∫123∑123
replace :=  {x:"y",≤:"\leq",≥:"\geq",∫:"\int",∑:"\sum"}
For what, with in replace
    StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %what%, %with%, All
MsgBox, %clipboard%
ExitApp
```

[image]